# isdigit in elisp

Tags: characters

I wanted to check that char is a digit by comparing its code with codes of 0 and 9, presuming that the digits codes are contiguous in code table:

```lisp
(let ((char ?\e))
  (if (and (>= char ?\0) (<= char ?\9))
      (message "aaa")
    (message "bbb")))
```

But it doesn't work: this code returns "aaa", even though `e` is not a digit.

What is wrong?

Comment: nothing wrong, Probably your question is about ?e ?0 and ?9 and not the slashed version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the backslashes before `e`, `0` and `9`.

```lisp
(let ((char ?e))
  (if (<= ?0 char ?9)
      (message "It's a digit")
    (message "It's not a digit")))
```

With the backslashes:

- `\e` is the escape char - ASCII 27.
- `\0` is the null char - ASCII 0.
- `\9` isn't special, so it's the same as `9` - ASCII 57.
- 27 is >= 0 and <= 57.

Comment: "\0 is null char ascii 0" - how to use ASCII 48 = "0" instead of ASCII 0?

Comment: This answer tells and shows you exactly how to do that.

Comment: See also `C-h i g (elisp)Basic Char Syntax` and `(elisp)General Escape Syntax`.  Note that `?\0` is being read as an octal value which is also why `?\9` is *not* treated the same way (as only the digits 0-7 are valid in octal).  You can specify octal character codes up to `?\777` with this syntax.